# Why the size of /proc directory is shown empty?

Tags: linux

Why is the command `du -sh` showing size 0 even the directory hold files? Also, what's the basic use of `/proc` directory?

Comment: That's normal. It's a virtual filesystem (reads and writes send data to/from the kernel) and doesn't actually occupy any space on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`proc(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> The proc file system is a pseudo-file system which is used as an interface to kernel data structures. It is commonly mounted at /proc.

which means `/proc` is not a directory on disk as other normal directories in your system, it just looks like one.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem, its 'files' are generated on the fly from different data structures.

The `df` tool gets the filesystem usage with the `statfs()` syscall. This syscall is implemented in every filesystem driver. But for `/proc`, it didn't have a point, because `/proc` doesn't contain any user files.